# Why won’t my react site deploy to netlify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, deployment, netlify

I recently finished working on a site. However every time I use Netlify for deployment I get a 404 error. I tried dragging the file, installing and uninstalling yarn.lock, and even reuploading to Codesandbox. This is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-bhaskara-m4br8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Did you add a `_redirects` file? See this [page](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/07/22/deploy-react-apps-in-less-than-30-seconds/) for instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is correctly deployed , make a _redirects file and put
/*    /index.html   200

In it